# Como faço para achar a média de uma nota? Em R

Tags: r

Preciso somar 2 notas digitadas para achar a média final em R `(Nota1 + 2*Nota2)/3` mas não sei como faz o calculo final para o script funcionar sem dar erro

```
print("Escreva seu nome") 

W<-scan(what="character",nmax=1)

print("Qual a nota1?")

X<-scan(what="character",nmax=1)

X<-as.numeric(X)

print("Qual a nota2?")

Y<-scan(what="character",nmax=1)

Y<-as.numeric(Y)
```

Linha do código que não sei.

```
if (Z<6) {print("Faça a G3.")} else {print("Aprovado.")}

RGui
```

Comment: Não é `Z <- (Nota1 + 2*Nota2)/3` mesmo antes da instrução `if`?

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer a média aritimética em R usamos a função `mean(c[x])` que recebe uma lista de números. Mas no seu caso você teria que fazer algo como:

```
// Para X = 10 e Y = 20
Z <- (X + 2*Y)/3
```

O resultado será: `> [1] 16.66667`

Comment: Pois é, eu fiz assim desde o inicio e apareceu o seguinte: Error in 2*Y : argumento não-numérico para operador binário

Comment: @CarlosWinter Esse erro parece ser porque no `scan` não é necessário `what="character"`. Basta `X<-scan(nmax=1)`, e `X` é imediatamente de classe `numeric`. O mesmo para `Y`.